# How to create an observableArray "before push" subscription?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to track down why I'm getting duplicate entries in an `observableArray`. Is there a way to subscribe to see before an item is added to an observable array?  I can see after an item is added by using a subscription like:

```
var myArr = ko.observablearray();
myArr.subscribe(function (changes) {
    changes.forEach(function (change) {
        var item = change.value;
        var itemStatus = change.status;
        if (itemStatus === "added") {

        } else if (itemStatus === "deleted") {

        }
    });
}, null, "arrayChange");
```

Comment: Can't you just locate all the places where the array is modified and debug those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You can use the signature `myArray.subscribe(func, null, "beforeChange")`.

---

An `observableArray` is just an `observable` with extra properties, so all `subscribe` features work normally. From [the relevant docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables):

> The `subscribe` function accepts three parameters: `callback` is the function that is called whenever the notification happens, `target` (optional) defines the value of `this` in the callback function, and `event` (optional; default is "change") is the name of the event to receive notification for.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to be notified of the value of an observable before it is about to be changed, you can subscribe to the `beforeChange` event.

Here's an example:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this, i = 1;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([i++, i++, i++]);  
  
  self.addItem = function() { self.items.push(i++); };
  
  self.items.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
    alert("Changed from: " + ko.toJSON(oldValue));
  }, null, "beforeChange");
  
  self.items.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("Changed to this new value: " + ko.toJSON(newValue));
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items"><li data-bind="text: $data"></li></ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Used this code and then was able to see my problem the first run through.  The new item was being pushed in an overridden prototype I had overlooked.